# Access static resources with Jersey 2.0, Tomcat 8

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

(Better structured I hope)

I am using @ApplicationPath(...) and an Application class extending ResourceConfig (without including Application in the web.xml):

Application.class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
     public Application() {
         packages("rest.resource");
     }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Test App</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Resource class:

```
@Path("/")
public class BaseResource {

    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @ManagedAsync
    public void get(@Context ServletContext context, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        asyncResponse.resume(Response.ok().entity("{ name: 'Hello' }").build());
    }
}
```

There is an "index.html" static resource in the "webapp" directory.

I can access resources using "localhost:8080/hello" without problem but not "index.html".

Where and how can I specify the location of the static resources so that I can access "index.html" using "localhost:8080/index.html?

**UPDATE: (following a comment from "peeskillet" which solved the issue)**

The actual problem was due to the use of "/*" in @ApplicationPath("/*").

So, I have changed the Application class to:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
     public Application() {
         packages("rest.resource");
     }
}
```

and I can now access "hello" using "localhost:8080/rest/hello.

Comment: There is a conflict with the default servlet that serves the static resources. You should change the `@ApplicationPath` to something other than `/*`

Comment: Many thanks peeskillet, I have replaced "/*" with "rest" and it works fine.